# how to cancel the routerLink upon a user prompt in angular 4+?

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to achieve the following good old functionality that we know from HTML

```
<a href='http://www.example.com' onclick="if ( window.confirm ('Are you sure you want to go there?') === false ) { return false; } ">goto example.com</a>
```

If the user selects the cancel option, browser does not move, end of story.

Well, how do you achieve that in the following Angular based HTML?

```
<a routerLink='/go-there'> go </a>
```

Clearly, this did not work:

```
<a routerLink='/go-there' onclick="if ( window.confirm ('Are you sure you want to go there?') === false ) { return false; } "> go </a>
```

Currently, I achieve this at the .ts while honoring the link under the routerLink reference, like this

```
const user_approval = window.confirm ('Are you sure you want to go there?');
if ( !user_approval ) {
  alert('Action is cancelled. \nYou are not going there.');
  return false;
}
```

This works but AFTER we already made it to routedLink! 
We could have avoided that.

How do you cancel the routerLink destination if the user responds towards changing his mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it in another way.
First, remove routerLink from your HTML, and use **(click)** instead of onclik :

```
<a (click)="check()">GO</a>
```

In your component, use the module router of Angular:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router) {}

  check() {
    const user_approval = window.confirm ('Are you sure you want to go there?');
      if ( !user_approval ) {
          alert('Action is cancelled. \nYou are not going there.');
          return false;
      } else {
          this.router.navigate(['/go-there']);
      }
  }
```

This way, you will execute the function that will either make you navigate or not depending on the user choice.

Comment: Julien, ho do we tackle this situation then? I'm almost there: `<br><a (click)="sure('delete', '/learning-plan/delete/{{ learningPlan.recID}}')">DELETE</a>`

Comment: Never mind, I figured it... `<br><a (click)="sure('delete', '/learning-plan/delete/' + learningPlan.recID)">DELETE RECORD #{{learningPlan.recID}}</a>` :)

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the click method + this.router.navigate, you can also use a CanDeactivate Guard on the route you want to add a prompt to. (https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate)

```
@Injectable()
export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate {

    constructor(){}

    canDeactivate(): boolean {
        let confirm = window.confirm('Are you sure you want to go there?');
        return confirm;
    }
}
```

This is a very basic example of a canDeactivate guard. Here is a demo plnkr (https://plnkr.co/edit/CW9ofxscCgaZMlWVrfer?p=preview)

---

As a side note, once you get into a more advanced implementation of a prompt, it'll most likely be asynchronous. In that case, you would wrap your implementation in an observable.

```
canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
        // example of an asynchronous prompt implementation
        bringUpSomePrompt('Are you sure you want to go there?', (confirm) => {
            observer.next(confirm);
            observer.complete();
        });
    });
}
```